# calculating $(1-i\sqrt{3})^{1+i}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How can I calculate this complex number :

$
(1-i\sqrt{3})^{1+i}
$

please correct or leave comment if my answer below is wrong (or put your own answer)...

Comment: This would be useful if you study the zeta function over the imaginary numbers $\zeta_{\mathbb{Z}[i]}(s)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1-i\sqrt{3})^{1+i}=e^{(1+i)\ln(1-i\sqrt{3})}=e^{(1+i)(\ln(2)+i(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi))}$

assuming that : $s=\ln(2)$ then

$
e^{(1+i)(s-i(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi))}=e^{[(s+(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi))+(si+i(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi))]}
$

Comment: Last step should be $e^{[(s-(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi))+(si+i(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi))]}$

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers : I did it because of $i*i(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi)=i^{2}(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi)=-(\frac{5\pi}{3}+2k\pi)$. isn't this right?

Comment: That's right, but it's not what you put.  You left out the minus sign